# Need .ami file wiith CentOS and perl modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, centos, amazon-ami

I need help putting together an Amazon ami file with the following perl modules:

```
Getopt::Long
List::MoreUtils
Parallel::ForkManager
Mail::CheckUser
Mail::CheckUser
Mail::CheckUser::Treat_Timeout_As_Fail
Mail::CheckUser::Treat_Full_As_Fail
Mail::CheckUser::Sender_Addr
Mail::CheckUser::Helo_Domain
Mail::CheckUser::Timeout
Mail::CheckUser::Debug
Parallel::ForkManager
Net::DNS
Data::Dumper
```

If you have a link to where I can find a CentOS ami file with these perl modules installed, or with the abiliy to install them, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go get a fresh copy of CentOS with perl. Run this command:

`yum install perl-Getopt-Long perl-List-MoreUtils perl-Parallel-ForkManager perl-Mail-CheckUser perl-Mail-CheckUser perl-Mail-CheckUser-Treat_Timeout_As_Fail perl-Mail-CheckUser-Treat_Full_As_Fail perl-Mail-CheckUser-Sender_Addr perl-Mail-CheckUser-Helo_Domain perl-Mail-CheckUser-Timeout perl-Mail-CheckUser-Debug perl-Parallel-ForkManager perl-Net-DNS perl-Data-Dumper`

You can also use cpan:

`cpan Getopt::Long List::MoreUtils Parallel::ForkManager Mail::CheckUser Mail::CheckUser Mail::CheckUser::Treat_Timeout_As_Fail Mail::CheckUser::Treat_Full_As_Fail Mail::CheckUser::Sender_Addr Mail::CheckUser::Helo_Domain Mail::CheckUser::Timeout Mail::CheckUser::Debug Parallel::ForkManager Net::DNS Data::Dumper`